# Is it possible to create a vue component to render a list of global components dynamically?

Tags: vue.js

I have some global-registered base components to be listed & rendered on the UI as the user drag and drop it on the layout editor. Then, I want it to be processed on a `<ComponentRenderer/>` component.

Inside of `<ComponentRenderer/>`, I currently have this kind of logic:

```html
<template>
    <div class="component-renderer">
        <radio-button
            :pageId="pageId"
            :input="input"
            :preview="preview"
            v-if="input.type == 'radio'"
        ></radio-button>

        <check-box
            :pageId="pageId"
            :input="input"
            :preview="preview"
            v-if="input.type == 'checkbox'"
        ></check-box>

        <standard-input
            :pageId="pageId"
            :input="input"
            :preview="preview"
            v-if="input.type == 'input'"
        ></standard-input>

        ...
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```

Now instead of hard-coding & comparing it manually using `v-if`, I want it to dynamically compare itself and render it's element and properties so that I don't need to register the other one when a new component was added. Something that looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="component-renderer" v-html="preRenderComponent"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      targetedComponent: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    computed: {
      preRenderComponent() {
        return this.$options.components.filter(
          component =>
            component.extendOptions.name.toLowerCase() == "base" + this.targetedComponent.type.toLowerCase() // E.g: 'input'
        );
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Is it possible? And if possible, how could I render the element and properties? Knowing that when I do `console.log(Vue.options.components)` and exploring it, it does not provide the element that gonna be rendered.

Comment: I think you are looking for `v-component` its `:is` attribute.

Comment: It's in fact simply named `<component>` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#component

Comment: thanks for the solution given, I'll tell you guys if it works :)

Comment: hey guys, it works, could you guys please post it as the answer so that the other can see the solution? or, I can post it by my self if you guys allows it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, I would say thanks for Steven Spungin & Phil for giving an information about this issue.

I tried to implements it on my code and it does work as I expected. For anyone who wondering what is it looks like, here I provides the code that have been implemented.

`LayoutRenderer.vue` :

```html
<template>
  <GridLayout
    v-if="pageComponents.length != 0"
    :layout.sync="pageComponents"
    :col-num="12"
    :row-height="30"
    :is-draggable="true"
    :is-resizable="true"
    :is-mirrored="false"
    :vertical-compact="true"
    :margin="[10, 10]"
    :use-css-transforms="true"
    :responsive="true"
    :auto-size="true"
  >
    <GridItem
      v-for="component in pageComponents"
      :key="component.i"
      :x="component.x"
      :y="component.y"
      :w="component.w"
      :h="component.h"
      :i="component.i"
    >
      <!-- <ComponentRenderer :component="component"></ComponentRenderer> -->
      <Component :is="named(component)"></Component>
    </GridItem>
  </GridLayout>
</template>

<script>
  import VueGridLayout from "vue-grid-layout";
  export default {
    components: {
      GridLayout: VueGridLayout.GridLayout,
      GridItem: VueGridLayout.GridItem
    },
    data() {
      return {
        pageComponents: []
      };
    },
    created() {
      this.fetchComponents();
    },
    methods: {
      fetchComponents() {
        let pageId = this.$route.params.component.pageId;

        this.$store.dispatch("components/fetchComponents", pageId).then(() => {
          this.pageComponents = this.$store.getters["components/components"];
        });
      },
      named(component) {
        let componentName = this.$options.filters.capitalize(component.type);
        return `Base${componentName}`;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```